# Python - SQLAlchemy: group_by() multiple columns, with sum()

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to craft the SQLAlchemy equivalent of

```
select count(urlpair.id), urlpairlabel.label, sum(tag.relevant)
from urlpair
left join tag
    on urlpair.id = tag.urlpair_id
join urlpairlabel
    on urlpair.id = urlpairlabel.urlpair_id
group by urlpairlabel.label, urlpair.url_1;
```

But a few of the combinations that I've tried seem to be **excessively** slow compared to the raw SQL

```
No errors; 45168 rows affected, taking 2.3 ms
```

vs my Postman to the API

```
def get_pair_stats():
stats = db.session \
    .query(
        func.count(Urlpair.id),
        Urlpairlabel.label,
        func.sum(
            case([(Tag.relevant == true(), 1)], else_=0))) \
    .outerjoin(Tag) \
    .join(Urlpairlabel) \
    .group_by(Urlpairlabel.label, Urlpair.url_1) \
    .all()

stats = [{
    'count': count,
    'label': label,
    'positives': int(positives)
} for (count, label, positives) in stats]

return stats
```

Results:

```
Status: 200 OK Time: 6226 ms Size: 3.7 MB
```

I noticed when I don't  supply both arguments to `group_by` it seems to be around 2s rather than 6-8. Is there some better way to create this statement?

Comment: I doubt they even do same thing, you do outjoin with Tag in SA but not in native query. Can you enable echo mode and see generated query?

Comment: Woops sorry, I just realized that the non join version wouldn't query the non-tagged pairs, updating my post right now.

Comment: Ok it's around 2s for the native now, but I feel like there still shouldn't be such a large discrepancy.

Comment: yet you are not filtering tags associated to url_pairs duo to outerjoin. Shouldn't change outerjoin to join?

Comment: @Reith The foreign key handles the filter on id to urlpair_id in SA if I remember correctly. I want outerjoin here because it returns results where there are no tags.

Comment: I may be wrong, but i guess joins won't work as you expect since you are selecting individual fields. can you add more filter clauses for join and check result? alternatively you can use select_from.